# Rails Rich Associations - undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have three basic models that I am working with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user  
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
end
```

Using this schema, I would assume the "Assignment" model is sort of the join table, which holds the information for which users belong to which groups.  So, what I am trying to do is, using a User object, find out what groups they belong to.

In Rail console, I am doing the following:

```
me = User.find(1)
```

Which returns the user object, as it should.  Then, I attempt to see which "groups" this user belongs to, which I thought it would go through the "Assignment" model.  But, I'm obviously doing something wrong:

```
me.groups
```

Which returns:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `groups' for #<User:0x007fd5d6320c68>
```

How would I go about finding out which "groups" the "me" object belongs to?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare the User - Groups relation in each model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :groups, through: :assignments
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end
```

---

Also, I recommend you to **set some validations** on the Assignment model to **make sure an Assignment always refers to a Group AND a User**:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user  
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :group_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  Good call on the validations as well.  I left these out of my original question for purposes of brevity.

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :groups, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user  
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end
```

Please refer [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 1):

Your `me` is of type `User` not `Assignment`. You want to do:

```
me.assignments.first.groups
```

This will give you all the groups belonging to the user's first assignment.  To get all the groups you could do as MrYoshiji has commented below:

```
me.assignments.map(&:groups)
```

Comment: This will only get the groups of the first assignment. Use `me.assignments.map(&:groups)` to get all groups of all assignments of the `me` User

Comment: @MrYoshiji, thanks for the comment.  I'll update my answer with this.  My initial intention was to point to the OP that `groups` need to be accessed through `assignments` and not `user`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define a has_many on groups. Try

```
me.assignments.first.group
```

should work.